# Center view inside another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view called profile which is taking `(0,0,320,60)` size in storyboard which is taking full width but 60 height, and i am trying to place another view called ranking inside it at the center and what ever the device is iPhone4s,5s,6s,6 it should just take my view and put it at the center.

Here is what i tried:

```
ranking.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 60);
ranking.center = self.Profile.center;
```

The current code is not centering my view In all devices. what can i do to do it dynamically ?

Comment: use constraints and autolayout, do **NOT** create UIs via code. It will be a pain in the *** getting it to work in the first place. And it will be even more work maintaining it.

Comment: @luk2302 : What was that *** ;) :D :P

Comment: profile view is shared view which is placed in 10 controllers, so i don't want to create it in 10 storyboards.

Comment: @FahimParkar dont tempt me :D

Comment: @NataMio then create a profile view and include it inside all the other places via container views.

Comment: @luk2302 , i so know that its a pain but i cannot avoid it sometimes..

Comment: @NataMio you can almost always avoid it! As long as you do not have strange relations between vertical and horizontal distances and spacings you can do pretty much anything by just using the interface builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AutoLayout with the following method:

```
+ (void)centerView:(UIView *)view inContainerView:(UIView *)containerView withSuperView:(UIView *)superView
{
    [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```

You can add the method above in your ViewController or in a helper class.
Remember to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false before using AutoLayout on your view.

So if `ranking` is your subview and `self.Profile` is your superView you can do the following.

```
UIView *ranking = [[UIView alloc] init];
ranking.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.Profile addSubview:ranking];
[[self class] centerView:ranking inContainerView:self.Profile withSuperView:self.Profile];
[self.Profile addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ranking attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:120]];
[self.Profile addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ranking attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:60]];
```